# why does media insertion produce different results in different servers?

Tags: php, wordpress

When using the standard editor and clicking on "Add media" my local site produces a different result that the productions site. Why?

on my local server:
     `<a href="http://mysite.fake/?attachment_id=34655" rel="attachment wp-att-34655">Test PDF</a>`

On the production server:
     `<a href="https://mysite.fake/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/test.pdf">Test PDF</a>`

I have matched every plugin to exact versions and exact settings (I think)
I have tried many iterations of echo, building the url separately,etc.